# ld: library not found for -lAnalytics error for expo bare workflow app on iOS

Tags: xcode, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I'm getting the following error from xcode when I try to build a project I ejected from expo:

```
ld: library not found for -lAnalytics
```

I have the expo Segment package installed, and have gone through the regular ejection process, installing and configuring unimodules, and running `npx install`

Where should I start looking for this error?   - Analytics (4.1.3) appears in my podfile.lock and I have an Analytics folder in the Library folder. I'm at a complete loss

Comment: open the xcworkspace file and not xcodeproj

Answer (score 0):

The fix was exactly as @brentvatne said, I had opened the project via xcodeproj NOT xcworkspace. Xcode remembers your choice so on subsequent openings of xcode it had defaulted to xcodeproj.

Solution: open project with xcworkspace.